# How to get details like PHP's stat() but using (raw) FTP (CURL)?

Tags: php, class, ftp, curl, stat

I'm new here. I've got a question related to PHP, FTP and CURL.

I need to emulate PHP's stat() with CURL FTP. I already know that it may take more than one command to do it. Here's what I've got so far (PHP/STAT ... FTP/CURL):

- dev
- ino
- mode ... LIST *
- nlink
- uid ... LIST *
- gid ... LIST *
- rdev
- size ... SIZE (or better still, use from LIST)
- atime
- mtime ... MDTM
- ctime
- blksize
- blocks

*How is FTP LIST used and parsed (preferably on a single file)?
What I need most are the values for atime and ctime, there rest is to be filled for the sake of having full functionality.

My end goal is to have a class for proper FTP access with streamWrapper functionality (so as to bypass allow_url_fopen).

Cheers!
Christian Sciberras

Comment: I don't think FTP supports those fields.

Comment: Can you specify which of those fields? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure how that works with cURL, but stat() support for FTP streams is currently like this: As of PHP 5.0.0: filesize(), filetype(), file_exists(), is_file(), and is_dir()  elements only. As of PHP 5.1.0: filemtime(). See http://de2.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.ftp.php

Comment: Makes sense. I think that pretty much answers my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Gordon's comment above.
If anything changes (i.e. I find some new stuff in the FTP spec) I'll update the answer.